# How to clear response caching on .Net Core after an create/update/delete?

Tags: caching, .net-core

I enabled the ResponseCaching on my .net Core 2.1 WebApi using the MSDN Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-2.1

It works correctly.

Now I want after an update, clear the cache globally.

Innocently, I thought using:

```
[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
```

will clear automatically the cache but it s not the case.

How can I do that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is nothing to “clear” in your case because this is cached on the client via headers in the response.

I think you are looking for something more of a data store like [Redis](https://redis.io) to cache this response data. The way you are doing it now the browser will cache locally and there is no way for you to invalidate that on the client

Comment: Thanks @Kyle Dodge for your answer. I understand now why I found no answer :). I will make search to invalidate the cache on client side.